# subject + to promise + pronoun + infinitive verb

Tags: word-usage, infinitives

I would like to ask if the following sentence is grammatically correct.

> My parents promised **me** to buy a new car.

I searched it and found out that  some native speakers find it acceptable but some not. On the other hand, I couldn't see this structure given as an example in any dictionary I checked out. Longman dictionaries especially warns not to use in this way in its grammar anecdotes.

[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=promised%20me%20to%20be&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpromised%20me%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0) "promise me to be"

So what do you think and if it is grammatically wrong, why?

Comment: @FumbleFingers This is what I read on the other  languages websites when I googled it..So this is not an information I get at first hand.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "You promised me to make me your queen" by Shakespear

Comment: @FumbleFingers "You promised me to insist upon her marrying him."  Jane Austen

Comment: What can I say? The "Shakespearean" one is apocryphal (not generally considered to have been written by the Bard at all), and even the Austen cite is centuries old. It's not valid syntax today.

Comment: ...you might find [this usage trend chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=promised+him+to&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpromised%20him%20to%3B%2Cc0) useful though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Fair enough.

Comment: @FumbleFingers so it is archaic and wrong but still in use to some extent.

Comment: Actually, this issue has been raised before on ELU. But be warned, John Lawler's answer kicks off with [Promise is a very troublesome verb, syntactically speaking.](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/116076/2637) Perhaps I should have closevoted as "duplicate".

Comment: The problem with _My parents promised me to buy a new car_ is that it's not clear whether the speaker winds up with the car or not; it could mean that the parents promised the speaker that the parents would buy a new car. The Indirect Object/Receiver role of _promise (to) me_ and the Benefactee/Receiver role of _buy (for) me_ are being confused. If it were _My parents promised me to buy me a new car_ it would be fine, though it would be better without the first _me_ : _My parents promised to buy me a new car_.

Comment: @JohnLawler I see your point. In the example sentence, adding indirect object pronoun, me, after infinite verb, buy, sounds good because it fits grammatically but there are some other examples I saw in use, such as "promise me to be careful" or " I want you to promise me to remember these promises no matter how busy and crazy our life and schedule get"  . I don't want to try to push the use in that way. I just want to ascertain why or how this rule developed in this way.

Comment: It isn't a rule; rather, it's an exception to [the usual rule of Equi](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf) that only occurs with _promise_. What you're noticing is that it's exceptional, **and** that it isn't totally ungrammatical, even so. That's how one starts to think about rules and exceptions, by noting the differences.

Comment: It is incorrect because you're messing with the normal locations of the direct and indirect object. The meaning of the sentence I believe is essentially that your parents are going to buy you a new car. Traditional structure would warrant subject(my parents) + promise + infinitive(to buy) + IO(me) + DO(a new car). In the original sentence it may read the the parents are promising to someone that you will be buying a new car similar to "my parents committed me to buy a new car".

Answer (score 1):

You could say "My parents promised to buy me a new car" or you could say "My parents promised me a new car". Both are acceptable in the US.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

> My parents promised me to buy a new car.

is at best confusing, at worst misleading. Such is because it could suggest that the subject (the parents) want the object (me) to buy a new car. This is due to it's similarities with other common statements using the same construction, but different verbs; verbs such as *ask* and *want*:

> My parents *asked me* to buy a new car.
>
> My parents *wanted me* to buy
>   a new car.

So, is the original statement it grammatically wrong? No, it isn't, but it's definitely confusing, and would benefit from being rephrased to something such as:

> My parents promised to buy *me* a new car.